# how to get the first part?

Tags: php

eg:the GET array: `$_GET['path']`

which value may be : `$_GET['path']==3`,`$_GET['path']==13_7`,`$_GET['path']==33_75_45`,...

no matter what value `$_GET['path']` has, i only want  the first part of the value. how to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list($a) =explode('_', $_GET['path']);
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: I think that'll throw a warning.

Comment: the `explode` will return more than one element, but you're only assigning one. i think it depends on your ini settings.

Comment: @Mark No, you can use `list` to list just one element, check the manual of `list`.

Comment: @xdazz: Okay...looks like you're right. It's when you have too many variables in `list()` and the `explode` doesn't return enough that it causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
function getNumber($n)
{
    $pos = strpos($n, "_");
    return ($pos === false ? $n : substr($n, 0, $pos));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get the job done:

```
$splitPath = strstr($_GET['path'], "_", true);
$path = strlen($splitPath > 0) ? $splitPath : $_GET['path'];
```

It can probably be shortened a bit, but the idea here is that in the end you will always just use the `$path` variable. If `$_GET['path']` contains `_` then whatever number is before it will be returned (due to the true argument in `strstr()`) and if not then just the value of `$_GET['path']` will be equal to `$path`. You may want to do some cleansing of the value though too, or at least make sure it's numeric ([is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)).

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that the value of `$_GET['path']` is delimited by `_` ? if so,

```
<?php
list($firstPart,) = explode('_', $_GET['path'], 2);
echo $firstPart;
```

could be the one you need.

Comment: why not pass `1` as the last arg?

Comment: well, because we only consider the first part, ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is confusing

This may help you
if u want to find the first part
example : name3example.com

```
<?php
    $result = strstr($_GET['path'], '3');
?>
```

// will return "name"

see the link for more details http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Or if u want to get the part of a string u can use 'substr' function of php

see the link for more details http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score -1):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in PHP to split an url in its various parts.

After that use [strrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to find the first occurrance of the required part in the path.

With [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) you can copy the first part of the path (up until the found _) and you're done.